# Не могу найти локатор яндекс поисковой строки Selenium

Tags: python

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
# Запрос пользователя
query = input("Введите запрос для поиска в Яндексе: ")

# Запуск браузера
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 # все операции будут ждать до 10 секунд

# Поиск в Яндексе
driver.get('https://ya.ru/')
time.sleep(5)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('text')  # находим поисковую строку
search_box.send_keys(query)  # вводим запрос
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # отправляем запрос

# Ожидание результатов поиска
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Переход по первой найденной ссылке
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="organic__url-text"]')
if results:
    first_result = results[0]
    first_result.click()

# Закрытие браузера
driver.quit()

Весь код

Пробовал  через Xpatch  тоже самое не находит поисковую строку пробовал через  css селектор. Драйввер открывает браузер но не вводит слово которое мне нужно в поисковик! Не знаю что и делать уже все перепробовал
```

Comment: А какую версию selenium вы используете?